# How could I pass parameter to this block

Tags: ruby, mail-gem

I want to send an email every day with a different attachment. So I think I should pass the parameter to mail's initialize block. I read some articles about `ruby block` but I can not find the right way to implement it. How could I do it the right way and why does the mail's initialize method pass a block? Thank you.

```
require 'mail'
class MailSender
  attr_accessor :created_at
  def initialize
    delivery_options = { 
      address: 'xxmail.com',
      port: 25,
      user_name: 'xxx@xxmail.com',
      password: 'xxxxxx',
      authentication: :login
    }
    Mail.defaults do
      delivery_method :smtp, delivery_options
    end
    self.created_at = DateTime.now.prev_day.strftime("%F")
  end

  def notify
    mail = Mail.new do
      from 'xxx@xxmail.com'
      to 'xxx@xxmail.com'
      subject 'mailtest'
      body 'The first mail.'
      add_file :filename => "#{created_at}.txt", :content => File.read("#{created_at}.txt")
    end
    mail.deliver!
  end
end
```

Comment: Try to avoid method names that are the same as the names of built-in methods. For example, perhaps "post" rather than "send".

Comment: It's not a requirement that you have to set every attribute of the mail in the initialize block, you can set them manually after the initialize block i.e. `mail.add_file <file>`. By passing a parameter, did you mean to pass the filename of the attachment ?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for point that. I will change that.

Comment: @limekin Yes, I mean pass the instance variable ```created_at``` to the block so  I can add different files. Just now I  add file before ```mail.deliver``` as you said, that works. Thank you limekin.